# Context state not updating after set method call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm a Noob in a quest to learn the React Kung-Fu techniques.

I'm struggling to implement useContext to update a set of values from two sibling components

**MainView.js**

```
export function MainView() {
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <canvas id='paper-canvas' resize='true' />
                <ViewProvider>
                    <Sketch />
                    <PathControls />
                </ViewProvider>
            <Header />
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

**ViewContext.js**

```
export const ViewContext = createContext([{}, () => {}]);

export const ViewProvider = (props) => {
    const [isPathVisibleState, setIsPathVisibleState] = useState(true);

    return(
        <ViewContext.Provider value={[isPathVisibleState, setIsPathVisibleState]}>
            {props.children}
        </ViewContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**PathControls.js**

```
export default function PathControls(props) {
const [isPathVisibleState, setIsPathVisibleState] = useContext(ViewContext);

    function handlePathVisibleChange() {
        console.log(isPathVisibleState);
        setIsPathVisibleState(isPathVisibleState => !isPathVisibleState);
    }

    return(
        <div className='path-line-controls container fixed-bottom'>
            <img src={pathLineIcon} alt='Show/Hide path line' title='Show/Hide path line' onClick={handlePathVisibleChange} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Sketch.js**

```
export default function Sketch(props) {
    const [isPathVisibleState, setIsPathVisibleState] = useContext(ViewContext);

    window.onload = function() {
        // Paperjs initialization settings
        paper.install(window);
        paper.setup('paper-canvas');

        // Creates a new path line that shows the connected dots
        path = new Path();
        path.strokeColor = 'black';
        path.visible = isPathVisibleState;

        view.onMouseDown = function(event) {
            addDot(event.point);
            console.log("MOUSEDOWN------","PATH:", isPathVisibleState);
        }
    }
    function addDot(point) {
        //...
    }
    return null;
}
```

My goal is to have **PathControls** component buttons to toggle a value **isPathVisibleState** true/false so the path drawn in the **Sketch** component **visible** property switch to true/false

My current setting does toggles **isPathVisibleState** true/false from the **PathControls** component but when I console that state variable from the **Sketch** component it always maintains the same initial value set in the Context component.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if `Sketch` re-renders when you change `isPathVisibleState`?

Comment: The Sketch component returns null, it does not renders anything, the drawing happens on the canvas tag in MainView. When I use useEffect() it does tracks the change correctly, but the examples I've seen don't use that hook, any ideas?

Comment: You didn't answer the question, does Sketch re-renders?

Comment: Sorry, to be honest I don't know, the component returns null and its local variables don't change

Answer (score 0):

It seems `Sketch` doesn't re-render altought `isPathVisibleState` changes, try adding a side-effect using `useEffect`:

```
export default function Sketch(props) {
  const [isPathVisibleState, setIsPathVisibleState] = useContext(ViewContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.onload = function() {
      // Paperjs initialization settings
      paper.install(window);
      paper.setup("paper-canvas");

      // Creates a new path line that shows the connected dots
      path = new Path();
      path.strokeColor = "black";
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    path.visible = isPathVisibleState;
    view.onMouseDown = function(event) {
      addDot(event.point);
      console.log("MOUSEDOWN------", "PATH:", isPathVisibleState);
    };
  }, [isPathVisibleState]);

  function addDot(point) {
    //...
  }
  return null;
}
```

Note that as your code is written right now, `Sketch` body will be executed on each re-render, that's why I moved it to `componentDidMount` cycle in the first `useEffect`.

If it doesn't work, you should check why `Sketch` doesn't re-render, adding a sandbox it always a good step.